# What parameter has controls.remove() method in winforms?

Tags: winforms, controls

What parameter has `controls.remove()` method in winforms? I want to remove some element from a form. What should I pass into the remove method - its id or something else?

Comment: A quick visit to the MSDN online library should sort you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `controls` property is a [`Control.ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx). To remove a control from this collection, you need to pass in an instance of the control you want to remove.

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove.aspx) has an example:

```
private void removeButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (panel1.Controls.Contains(removeButton))
   {
      panel1.Controls.Remove(removeButton);
   }
}
```

---

To answer the question in your comment:

You cannot remove it by its id or name, but you can find the instance of your control by passing its name into the [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) method on the `Controls` property. This returns as array of all controls that have the specified name.

Comment: i didn't have the instance, because the object is created in function, and i want to remove him when i again call this function , can i remove it by its id or name ?